# Change switch behavoir with foreach

Tags: xml, powershell, switch-statement

I've a XML file containing:

```
<Setting>
    <Application Id="Main_Form" Name="Office365: Run scripts">
        <task Id="1" Script="SPO-SCDefaults.ps1" Name="Create default Site Collection structure" />
        <task Id="2" Script="SPO-FileMig.ps1" Name="Datacopy to SharePoint cloud" />
        <task Id="3" Script="EXO-AddAdminDistri.ps1" Name="Exchange: Add admin user to distributiongroups" />
        <task Id="4" Script="empty.ps1" Name="Todo..." />
    </Application>
</Setting>
```

And a script like:

```
$Xml = [xml](Get-Content $ScriptPath\Settings.xml)

function Do-PromptTask
{   
    $task1 = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.name[0]
    $task2 = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.name[1]
    $task3 = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.name[2]
    $task4 = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.name[3]
    $task1_exec = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.script[0]
    $task2_exec = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.script[1]
    $task3_exec = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.script[2]
    $task4_exec = $Xml.Setting.Application.task.script[3]

    switch -wildcard (Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" @($task1,$task2,$task3,$task4))
    {
        $task1{$task_result = $task1_exec}
        $task2{$task_result = $task2_exec}
        $Task3{$task_result = $task3_exec}
        $Task4{$task_result = $task4_exec}
        ""{Exit} #End Selection (cancel selected)
        "*"{Do-PromptTask} #Keep prompting until "cancel" selected
    }
    Write-Host "$ScriptPath\Bin\$task_result"
}

Do-PromptTask
```

I think it should be easier to change it to something like:

```
function Do-PromptTask
{
    switch -wildcard (Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" @($task['name'])) # Array of all names
    {
        foreach ($node in $Xml.Setting.Application.task) {
            $task['name']{$task_result = $task_exec['script']}
        }
        ""{Exit} #End Selection (cancel selected)
        "*"{Do-PromptTask} #Keep prompting until "cancel" selected
    }
    Write-Host "$ScriptPath\Bin\$task_result"
}

Do-PromptTask
```

Is this possible, and am I on the correct way perhaps? I would like to be able to generate the listings in the form dynamically when a item is added in the XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Switch` for this either since you want it to be dynamic like that. I'd use a hashtable with your task names as keys and your task executable as values in the form of scriptblocks. Something like this:

```
Do{
    $AllTasks = @{}
    $Xml.Setting.Application.task | ForEach{$AllTasks.add($_.Name,[scriptblock]::Create($_.Script))}
    $Sel = Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" $AllTasks.Keys
    If(!$Sel -match "Cancel"){$AllTasks[$Sel].Invoke()}
}While($Sel -notmatch "Cancel")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would avoid using `switch` altogether for this, and do it like this:

```psh
function Do-PromptTask
{   
    $sel = $null
    while ($Xml.Setting.Application.task.name -notcontains $sel) {
        $sel = Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" $Xml.Setting.Application.task.name
        if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($sel)) {
            exit
        }
    }
    $task_result = & ($Xml.Setting.Application.task | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $sel } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Script)

    Write-Host "$ScriptPath\Bin\$task_result"
}
```

Basically take advantage of the array properties of your XML and never refer to individual indexes.

Comment: I'm debugging the script now, I think I made a error in my XML, when I do a `Write-Host $Xml.Setting.Application.task.name` the return is empty. I'll try both examples today. Thanks for the effort !

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer using the code from @TheMadTechnician , below the code that executed the form and returns the scriptname within a path. Quite a challenge but it works with the XML and is dynamic.

```
$Xml = [xml](Get-Content $ScriptPath\Settings.xml)
. "$ScriptPath\Bin\O365-Functions.ps1"

$Sel = $null

Do {
    $AllTasks = @{}

    $Xml.Setting.Application.task | ForEach { $AllTasks.add($_.Name,[scriptblock]::Create($_.Script)) }
    $Sel = Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" @($AllTasks.Keys)

    $TaskResult = $ScriptPath+"\Bin\"+$AllTasks[$Sel].ToString()
    Invoke-Expression "&'$TaskResult'"

} While( $Sel -notmatch $null )
```

Thanks for the help!